# Azure DevOps how to edit Wiki page via REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019

I want to edit a Azure DevOps wiki page over the REST API (Azure DevOps Server 2019.0.1).

**When I run this PowerShell script:**

```
#VARIABLES
$api = "api-version=5.0"
$root = "http://136.202.18.216:8070/Samples"
$personalToken = "uwawlzqp6j7i1nd5dasspwkwp63tr2w2sxb5563zrla2bivynbza"

#AUTHORIZATION
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = ('Basic {0}' -f $token)
    "If-Match"      = '*'
}

#PROJECT VARIABLES
$project = "Framework%20A"
$pageToUpdate = "/Seite2"

#BODY
$body = @"
    {
        "content": "Hello"
    }
"@

#GET
$url = "$root/$project/_apis/wiki/wikis/2e887fde-ce76-4180-aa8d-f26ed4799eb3/pages?version=wikiMaster&path=$pageToUpdate&includeContent=True&$api"
$content = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers
Write-Host "$($content.path) = $($content.content)" -ForegroundColor Yellow

#PUT
$url = "$root/$project/_apis/wiki/wikis/2e887fde-ce76-4180-aa8d-f26ed4799eb3/pages?version=wikiMaster&path=$pageToUpdate&$api"
$update = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header -Body $body -Verbose
Write-Host $update.content -ForegroundColor Yellow
exit(0)
```

**The consolen output is:**

```
/Seite2 = Seite 2 Content
AUSFÜHRLICH: PUT http://136.202.18.216:8070/Samples/Framework A/_apis/wiki/wikis/2e887fde-ce76-4180-aa8d-f26ed4799eb3/pages?version=wikiMaster&path=/Seite2&api-version=5.0 with -1-byte payload
Invoke-RestMethod: {"$ id": "1", "innerException": null, "message": "The required \" IfMatch \ "header specified in the request is an invalid page version Version of the
Wiki page as \ "IfMatch \" header for the request. \ R \ nParameterName: IfMatch "," typeName ":" Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer.InvalidArgumentValueException,
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer "," TypeKey ":" InvalidArgumentValueException "," error code ": 0," eventId ": 0}
In C:\Users\mkober\Desktop\Azure DevOps Skripte (Bearbeitung)\WikiAPI.ps1:34 Zeichen:11
+ $update = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -ContentType "appli ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

The first line `/Seite2 = Seite 2 Content` is the result of a successful `get` request from the page I want to edit. The `put` request occures the error. What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE: (Working Example)**

```
#VARIABLES
$api = "api-version=5.0"
$root = "http://136.202.18.216:8070/Samples"
$personalToken = "uwawlzqp6j7i1nd5dasspwkwp63tr2w2sxb5563zrla2bivynbza"

#AUTHORIZATION
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = ('Basic {0}' -f $token)
    "If-Match"      = '{0}'
}

#PROJECT VARIABLES
$project = "Framework%20A"
$pageToUpdate = "/Seite2"

#BODY
$body = @"
    {
        "content": "Hello"
    }
"@

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#GET
$url = "$root/$project/_apis/wiki/wikis/2e887fde-ce76-4180-aa8d-f26ed4799eb3/pages?version=wikiMaster&path=$pageToUpdate&includeContent=True&$api"
$content = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers
$etag = $content.Headers.ETag
$headers.'If-Match' = $headers.'If-Match' -f $etag
Write-Host "$($content.path) = $($content.content)" -ForegroundColor Yellow

#PUT
$url = "$root/$project/_apis/wiki/wikis/2e887fde-ce76-4180-aa8d-f26ed4799eb3/pages?version=wikiMaster&path=$pageToUpdate&$api"
$update = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers -Body $body -Verbose
Write-Host $update.content -ForegroundColor Yellow
exit(0)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `If-Match` header you can't just put `'*'`, you need to put there the `ETag` of the page.

How do you get it? in your first `GET` call use `Invoke-WebRequest` (instaed of `Invoke-RestMethod`), now in the response you will get also headers response and there the `ETag` exist:

```
$page = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url ...........
$etag = $page.Headers.ETag
$headers = @{
    "Authorizaion = ....."
    "If-Match" = $etag
}
```

Now the second `Invoke-RestMethod` will work to update the page.

Comment: thanks a lot Shayki, I update my question with the working example. Greetings to you.