# Is it possible to upload a new wiki page to a provisioned wiki using a bash script?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to upload the contents of a .md file to my organization's provisioned wiki using a bash script, but it's not working as expected. Although the logs indicate that the upload is successful, after a few minutes, I receive a 503 error, even though all the Azure DevOps services are online. Here's the bash script I'm using:

```
PAT=$(secretValue) 
README_PATH="$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/redacted/redacted/infra-pipeline-readme.md" WIKI_API_URL="https://dev.azure.com/redacted/redacted/_apis/wiki/wikis/redacted.wiki/pages?path=redacted/redacted&api-version=7.2-preview.1"
CONTENT=$(cat "$README_PATH")
echo "$CONTENT"
RESPONSE=$(curl -v -u :$PAT $WIKI_API_URL -X PUT -H "Content-Type: text/markdown" -H "Content-Length: ${#CONTENT}")
echo "API Response: $RESPONSE"
```

I checked the Azure DevOps Services documentation and learned that the 'Add or edit pages from Repos > Files or Code > Files' operation is not available for provisioned wikis. Does this apply to the REST API as well? Can we add a new page through the REST API?

I tried changes the URL path, and API versions. But I keep getting the 503 error as a response.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible if you are using this API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/pages/create-or-update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP

Additionally, check this post to update existing pages: [Azure DevOps how to edit Wiki page via REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57056375/azure-devops-how-to-edit-wiki-page-via-rest-api). And use `Content-Type: application/json`

I'm unfamiliar with curl... but maybe you need to add `-d` parameter to pass the content? To pass content, use json format:

`{"content":"YOUR_CONENT"}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have been using that API. As a response I get an error 503 even though all Azure devops services are online. In the raw logs of the pipeline that runs this script. I can see that something gets uploaded so it does work in some way but at the end I get the error and nothing gets uploaded.

Comment: @Rakuzan check your content. It should be with JSON format: `{"content":"your_ makdown_conent"}`

Answer (score 0):

The rest api is correct here: Pages - [Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/pages/create-or-update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP)

The curl sample as below:

```
- bash: |
    organization=""
    project=""
    wiki=""
    pagepath="wiki/SamplePage"
    README_PATH="README.md"
    pat=$(PAT)
    url="https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/wiki/wikis/$wiki/pages?path=$pagepath&api-version=7.2-preview.1"

    echo $url

    # Encode the Personal Access Token (PAT)
    encoded_pat=$(printf "%s"":$pat" | base64)

    # Read the content of the READdMe file
    content=$(cat "$README_PATH")

    # Convert the content to JSON
    json_content=$(jq -n --arg content "$content" '{"content": $content}')

    # Update the wiki page
     curl -X PUT $url -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "Authorization: Basic $encoded_pat" -d "$json_content"
    
    echo "Wiki page '$pagepath' updated."
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your sample. I made some changes. I'm now getting a new error which is:

`{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"One or more ancestor pages of the page '/1765/redacted' does not exist.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Wiki.Server.WikiAncestorPageNotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Wiki.Server","typeKey":"WikiAncestorPageNotFoundException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}Wiki page '/1765/redacted' updated.`

Comment: Which is weird because the url to that page is:
`https://dev.azure.com/redacted/redacted/_wiki/wikis/redacted.wiki/1765/redacted`

Comment: The error happens if the `path` is not correct. If you have subpage between root wiki and target page, eg: wiki/1765/SamplePage, need to create subpage 1765 firstly. Please check the `$url` output in the task(echo $url) for the rest api url, make sure it's correct.

Comment: Hi @Rakuzan, is there any update? Please make sure page 1765 exists as prerequisite, then you can create the 1765/redacted page. Let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `az devops wiki page` command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/wiki/page?view=azure-cli-latest

```
az devops wiki page create --path 'my page' --wiki myprojectwiki --file-path a.txt --encoding utf-8
```

How to use PAT to sign in: [Sign in with a personal access token (PAT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I have tried using az devops wiki page create, however I was getting the following error: ERROR: 'wiki' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.

Looking at my WIKI_API_URL variable, it is working so I'm not sure why I'm getting that error